# Transparent rectangle in the Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I need show video into VideoView which locate inside of activity with style (extends of Theme.Dialog).

```
<resources>
    <style name="Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_surface"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and I have the next:
[image]

As you can see in the left-top corner is transparently. How can I disable that?

Comment: Resolution of the problem is correct style for activity on:

    <resources>
        <style name="Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        </style>
    </resources>

Only in that case you can't close activity by means tap on the gray area around window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution of the problem is correct style for activity on:

```
<resources>
  <style name="Custom">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Only in that case you can't close activity by means tap on the gray area around window